# Is there any scientific evidence that a human has ever grown a third set of teeth?

Tags: human-biology, development, stem-cells, teeth

This is about the possibility (or lack thereof) for a person to re-grow a new "permanent tooth" or set of teeth, to replace the teeth that grew after their milk teeth fell out.

I had earlier seen some anecdotal evidence on the internet that this would have happened to some people.

Anyway, what I wanted to ask is if there is any scientific evidence (e.g. properly recorded unusual medical phenomena) that shows that a person has grown a tooth (or a set of teeth) to replace their permanent teeth?

Comment: Hello. Can you please link to your sources?

Comment: I think this question would be more on-topic on [skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com). Someone who grows a new set of teeth after seing an UFO sounds quite obviously like some kind of a stupid fake story.

Comment: My question is not because of the anecdotal evidence (I am not asking anyone to validate the anecdotal evidence). This question could stand on its own without the references to the anecdotal evidence and I have not been able to locate those sources.

Comment: I made some edits to this that removed the voodoo to make it more of a stem cell and development based question

Comment: @rhill45, it is better without the voodoo. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are legitimate case reports in credited journals of hyperdontia, or the condition of having supernumerary teeth. Such cases are often associated with congenital syndromes-- cleft lip and palate, trichorhinophalangeal syndrome, cleidocranial dysplasia, and Gardner's syndrome. I included a case report and a comprehensive review for you below.

[Case Report](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21967947) from American Journal of Orthodontic Dentofacial Orthopedics, 2011.

[Comprehensive Review](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25500927) from Journal of Oral Science, 2014.

Comment: Googling images of this is always a fun weekday evening past-time...